# Finish the service and stop the thread

Tags: c#

I have several services and use threads to implement each one. The services are executed sequentially. Let me just pick up one for demo purpose.

```
            services[1] = new RProcessing() { ConsoleInfoColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan };
            success = services[1].Start();
            if (success)
            {
                OutputUtils.WriteLogInfo("Service " + services[1].Name + " started...");
            }
            else
            {
                OutputUtils.WriteLogInfo("Service " + services[1].Name + " failed to start...");
                previousStartup = false;
                services[0].Stop();
            }
```

Inside RProcessing.

```
    public RProcessing()
    {
        worker = new Thread[1]; // Only one thread
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            worker[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServiceLoop));
            worker[i].Name = "R Thread_" + i.ToString();
        }
        // processing
    }
    public bool Start()
    {
        foreach (Thread t in worker)
            t.Start();
        return (true);
    }

    public bool Stop()
    {
        if (_isRunning)
        {
            _isRunning = false;
        }
        _isRunning = false;
        base.Dispose();
        WriteLogInfo("Shutdown of R Processor complete");
        return (true);
    }

    public void ServiceLoop()
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        WriteLogInfo("Starting ServiceLoop() for: " + Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(RProcessing)).FullName);
        string s;
        while (_isRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            s = null;
            try
            { 
                WriteLogInfo(" processing "+s);
                Thread.Sleep(864);// 24 hours.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLogError("Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "     " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }
        if (this._isRunning)
        {
            WriteLogInfo("Restarting thread due to failure...");
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLogError("Error restarting thread... " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Only there is one thread, I want to finish it then go back the next service. However it is always inside the ServiceLoop. How can break it? Just call Stop()?

Answer (score 0):

Well, comment is misleading. Thread will sleep for 864 milliseconds, and not 24 hours.

```
Thread.Sleep(864);// 24 hours.
```

If you really intend to sleep that long in a loop, then use ManualResetEvent so that you could abort the wait at any time.

```
ManualResetEvent cancelEvent;

in loop:
 if(cancelEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromHours(24))){
    break;
 }

and, in Stop method:
 cancelEvent.Set();
```

Also remove  that:

```
if (this._isRunning)
{
    WriteLogInfo("Restarting thread due to failure...");
    try
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLogError("Error restarting thread... " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

And make sure that _isRunning is volatile, otherwise it may be cached and not updated in another thread. Your service will exit peacefully when you call Stop().

Comment: Can I  this._isRunning = false;
                    Stop();
                    Thread.Sleep(86400);

Comment: Stop is already setting _isRunning to false, and what would be the point of waiting a day after that?

Comment: I want to run the service everyday, so wait 24 hrs rerun the service to deal with the update data.

Comment: Well, if you want to do something so rarely, i suggest you use windows scheduled task, that will run some command line program. And if you want to do it within an application, then you can use a Timer. I see no reason for creating a thread that will sleep for a day.